# Getting a "declaration is needed" error but don't know what to do (Xcode)

Tags: ios, swift

Just added in an alert and gets a "declaration needed" error at the end, I already added in the ";" the system suggested but still doesn't work, the codes are as below:

```
class SignUpViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBAction func BackToFirstPageButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    performSegueWithIdentifier("BackToLogInPage", sender: self)
  }

  @IBOutlet var UsernameTextField: UITextField!

  @IBOutlet var PasswordTextField: UITextField!

  @IBOutlet var EmailTextField: UITextField!

  @IBAction func SignUpButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    if UsernameTextField.text == "" || PasswordTextField.text == "" || EmailTextField.text == "" {

        let SignUpAlert = UIAlertController (title: "Error in form", message: "Please fill in the blanks", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        SignUpAlert.addAction((UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in

            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        })))

        self.presentViewController(SignUpAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

  func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
  }

  func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }

};
```

This last bracket and a colon is where I get a declaration error. Please help. First time posting here so please tell me if I'm missing anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a closing brace missing in this method

```
@IBAction func SignUpButton(sender: AnyObject) {
 ...
}
```

You can check that by hovering the cursor over the small column between the line numbers and the code – which highlights the current scope – or by folding the method when you click on the little disclosure triangle which appears left from the method declaration line.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing a closing bracket on the if statement inside your  SignUpButton method

Try:

```
class SignUpViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBAction func BackToFirstPageButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    performSegueWithIdentifier("BackToLogInPage", sender: self)
  }

  @IBOutlet var UsernameTextField: UITextField!

  @IBOutlet var PasswordTextField: UITextField!

  @IBOutlet var EmailTextField: UITextField!

  @IBAction func SignUpButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    if UsernameTextField.text == "" || PasswordTextField.text == "" || EmailTextField.text == "" {

        let SignUpAlert = UIAlertController (title: "Error in form", message: "Please fill in the blanks", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        SignUpAlert.addAction((UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in

            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        })))

        self.presentViewController(SignUpAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
  }

  func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
  }

  func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one last closing bracket '}' and you can like Alessandro Chiarotto said remove the ';'

Answer (score -1):

In swift you don't need ';' like objective-c

Comment: Right but a semicolon after the pair of braces of a method doesn't cause an compiler error.

Comment: and add another "}" at the end